# Show CKEditor on each row of a table

Tags: php, codeigniter, ckeditor

I want CKEditor to be shown on each row ot a table, but it appears only on the first row. On the other rows only textarea is shown, without CKEditor. I use Codeigniter. That's my view:

```
<?php
foreach ($query as $row) {
    echo "<table border='1'>";
    echo "<tr>";
    ?>
    <td class='col-md-2'>
    <textarea  name="content" id="content"></textarea> 
    <?php 
    echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor);
    ?>
    </textarea></td></tr>
    <?php
}
?>
```

My controller is:

```html
<?php
//some code

        $data['ckeditor'] = array(
 
   
   'id'  =>  'content',
   'path' => 'js/ckeditor',
 
   
   'config' => array(
    'toolbar'  =>  "Full",  
    'width'  =>  "550px", 
    'height'  =>  '100px', 
 
   ),
    
    )    
   )
  );
```

How should be done to be shown on each row?

Comment: use class instead of ID.. because it will create ID duplication in while loop..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
****Download ckeditor from here :**
```

http://ckeditor.com/download (basic packeg)

```
**Code**:-
<html>     
<head>           
<title>CKEditor with jQuery</title>         
<!-- JQUERY LIBRARY -->         
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/adapters/jquery.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript">                               
$(function(){                                            
$('.content').ckeditor();                             
});             
</script>       
</head>     
<body>         
    <h1>CKEditor with jQuery</h1>         
        <form id="editor_form" method="post" action="index.html">             
            <textarea class = "content"></textarea><br>         
            <textarea class = "content"></textarea><br>          
            <textarea class = "content"></textarea><br>          
            <textarea class = "content"></textarea><br>          
            <textarea class = "content"></textarea><br>          
            <textarea class = "content"></textarea><br>          
            <textarea class = "content"></textarea><br>          
            <textarea class = "content"></textarea><br>          
            <textarea class = "content"></textarea><br> 
        </form>
</body> 
</html>

**Folder Structure** (in xampp/htdocs i have created a folder name stackoverflow):-
```

http://prntscr.com/6i9e6w

Comment: I made the folder structure, It's not problem :)

Comment: I can't, because I don't have 15 reputation.

Comment: Ohk, try to earn and then do it.:):):):):)

Comment: It's ok no problem.:):)

Answer (score 2):

Try to give id dynamically rather than 'content'.

Comment: How to give id dynamically?

Comment: Try this,                                                                                              <?php $cnt =0;
foreach ($query as $row)
{
echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
?>
<td class='col-md-2'>
<textarea  name="content" id="content<?php echo $cnt;?>"  ></textarea> 
<?php echo display_ckeditor($ckeditor); ?>
</textarea></td></tr>
<?php
}

Comment: 'id'  =>  'content<?php echo $cnt;?>',    I changed this in my controller, but still no effect.

Comment: in controller,  put 'id' => 'content'.rand() In view put id='content<?php echo rand()?>'

Comment: It's the same, only on the first row is CKEditor, and the next textarea.